# Make :visited work on links that have non http href

Tags: html, css

I'm using links like `Whatsapp://send?phone=xxxxx&text=blablabla`

When I visit the link, it opens the Whatsapp app so chrome probably has no idea if that link was visited or not.

A workaround is to give it a class when it's clicked and apply the CSS of that class, but that seems farfetched to me and I'm wondering if there is another way?

Comment: can you show up the code that don't work for you?

Comment: As simple as `<a href = "Whatsapp://send?phone=xxxxx&text=blablabla">Click me </a>`